# I am confused about the apparent fact that the numerical values of the Planck units are unchanged by exchanging $\hbar$ for $h$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-constants, metrology

Can you confirm that each of Max Planck's original equations for Planck units included $h/2π$.

If yes, does this explain how $ħ$ can be used In Planck's formulas without changing the numerical results of the calculations?

Comment: Link to reference? Which page?

Comment: Why is this an “apparent fact”? What calculation did you actually do?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Planck's original definitions used $h$ rather than $\hbar$. However, the numerical values for Planck units are *not* unchanged if you replace $\hbar$ by $h$. According to the Wikipedia article on [Planck units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units):

> [Planck's] definitions differ from the modern ones by a factor of
> $\displaystyle \sqrt {2\pi }$, because the modern definitions use
> $\hbar$ rather than $h$.

Eric Weisstein's [World of Physics](https://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/PlanckTime.html) gives the two different values for the Planck time, for example:

$\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{Gh}{c^5}} = 1.35125 \times 10^{-43}$ seconds

$\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{G\hbar}{c^5}} = 5.39072 \times 10^{-44}$ seconds

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  chatGPT v 3.5, told me that the numerical value of the Planck units is unchanged by the substitution of h-bar for h.  This made no sense when you consider that h-bar has only about 16% of the value of h.  The values of the Planck units had to have changed by this substitution

Comment: @FrankBurdge I think the lesson from that is don't trust ChatGPT's answers.